# Android Studio can't see my phone, but PC can

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed newest android studio but I could not find the way to gather log, so I installed 2.3.3. But it says "unable to create debug bridge". 
And android studio shows "no connected devices".

I tried run-edit configuration-target-usb devices, but doesn't work.
I switched MTP to PTP but no work.

BUT my computer sees my phone and I can access all files in my phone through file explorer when MTP.

Windows 7 32 bit
LG G4

I just need to get log from my phone to see it, because there are something wrong with app that I made.

any tips?

*BTW, I have tried with other PC which is same spec as my PC with same phone, and it worked at that time(but it was maybe 2.3.2).

Comment: [The newest android studio is 3.1.1.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and check your SDK

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is problem with driver

I had the same problem and installing `LG Bridge` solved that problem

Open

http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers

And choose `LG Mobile Drivers`

Comment: worked!! thanks. I thought driver is not needed since pc can see a phone but it was needed

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have virtualization on in the bios. This was a big issue for me last time... It can be called VT-x.

Enable the developer option in you device.

Install Wondershare MobileGo 8.5.0 and mange with this you device.

Or

First make sure that you have virtualization on in the bios. This was a big issue for me last time... It can be called VT-x.

Next, Install the correct usb drivers

What I forgot to do was install the android_winusb file in the usb_driver folder. The path should be sdk\extras\google\usb_driver. In my case, C:\Users\Ruchir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

After doing that, go back to device manager and go to the install as path. At the bottom of that should be another option:

Let me pick from a list of devices on my computer

Select your android phone, it shouldn't have a yellow explamation point over it any more. After that, select composite ADB Interface. THATS IT.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying enabling Developer Options on your phone?
More info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html) and enabling the mode [here](https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/34-useful-things-you-can-do-in-android-developer-options-new-3590299/).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1) Enable the developer option in you device.

2) Enable the USB debugging option in you device.

3) Install proper USB mobile driver otherwise choose Auto Download driver on your PC.